# How did the Millenium Falcon get so close to Starkiller at light speed?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I was watching *The Force Awakens* the other day and I wondered something. The novelization of *A New Hope* and countless other books in the EU say that its impossible to go to lightspeed in the presence of a strong gravitational field, in other words, a planet. Also, I read that a planet can pull a ship out of lightspeed.

So how is that Han got so close to Starkiller at lightspeed?

Comment: I believe gravity pulling ships out of hyperspace isn't canon.

Comment: Where a SW film contradicts a SW novel, the film always wins.

Comment: *Plays funeral dirge for the Interdictor Cruiser*

Comment: @SS-3 it IS canon as there is a rebels episode centered about an interdictor star destroyer

Comment: btw http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112032/hyperspace-and-gravity-wells

Comment: Related - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112078/11841

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He... erm ... pre-programmed it.

> *As the wide-eyed Finn scrambled for a seat and harness and found
> himself wishing for a number of very large, soft pads, Chewbacca
> groaned his readiness. Han studied the readouts before him. The
> Wookiee raised a hand over his own console. “And…” Han followed the
> declining fractions intently. “Now!”*
>
> *Human and Wookiee hands flew over the main console, supplementing as
> best they could the approach and landing information they had
> preprogrammed into the Falcon’s instrumentation. Not unexpectedly,
> more than one last-second override was required in order to make the
> ship do something that was against its nature and perform maneuvers
> for which it had never been designed.*
>
> <sub><sup>[SW: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

Most of his work at the console seems to be aimed at **stopping the ship from aborting the approach** rather than actually timing the landing.

Comment: Ahem? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112032/hyperspace-and-gravity-wells/112033#112033